# HTML elements only show after i reload page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this javascript code that inserts a label into an existing html page. However, it only shows when i reload the page. Like if i visit the page it doesn't show. once im at the page and reload, it then shows. How do i fix it so it shows right when i visit the page?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    insertlabel();
});

function insertlabel() {
    var $label = $('<label>test</label>');
    //place them on the page
    $('.div1').after($label);
}
```

Comment: please show the html as well

Comment: it would be easier to seek help if you include your markup and post it on jsfiddle or inside SO itself

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it makes a difference, but I always define my functions inside $(document).ready();

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
    function insertlabel() {
        var $label = '<label>test</label>';
        $('.div1').after($label);
    }

        insertlabel();

    });
```